# How to make 3-D time series plots

Tags: r, 3d, time-series

I have time series data on 10 individuals, similar to what is created below. I am looking for a way to make a 3-D plot similar to this example:
[image]

Except I want each unique `ID` to be where year is in the picture

```r
set.seed(123)
ID <- rep(1:10, each = 500)
Time = rep(c(1:500),10)
Var <- rnorm(5000)
data <- data.frame(
  ID = factor(ID),
  Time = Time,
  Variable = Var
)
```

Comment: does the [ggridges package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggridges/vignettes/introduction.html) do what you want?

Comment: @Ben I am playing around with ggridges, but haven't gotten it to work correctly yet. In the picture above I need to replace year with `ID`, the x axis with `Time`, and millions (the height), with `Variable`

Comment: ggridges doesn't do "true" 3D, and the results for these data are pretty ugly: `ggplot(data, aes(x=Time,y=ID,height=abs(Variable))) +
  geom_ridgeline(fill="lightblue",scale=0.5)`

Answer (score 2):

As a very quick, and ugly start, try

```
library(plot3D)
## rearrange data into matrix form
m <- matrix(
  data$Variable,
  nrow=length(unique(data$ID)))
hist3D(z = m)
```

This doesn't look at all like your example plot; on the other hand, your data don't look much like the data in this plot.  Things I haven't played around with yet:

- axis labels
- making sure the matrix is actually oriented in the right way (this will be a lot easier with real data!)
- changing aspect ratio